# Is it possible to estimate the time needed to train a machine learning model given a size of data and hardware specification?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, time-complexity

I am planning to make small Tensor Flow image classification project, which is expected to run on machines with low processing power, and one of the concerns I was asked about was the time needed to train the model.

The project is still in the conception stage and no clear boundary is made.
But assuming that we will use Tensor flow for Python, with a simple Neural Network for say n images data set, is there a way to estimate or predict the time required to train the model before performing the training given the hardware in use?

I have asked one of my colleagues who works in NN and he said that maybe we could calculate the time needed by measuring the time for the first epoch and making an estimation how many epochs needed afterwards. Is this is a valid way? If yes then is it even possible to estimate the number of epochs needed? And either cases is there a way to calculate it before performing any training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definite way of finding the number of epochs to which the model converges. It is one of the hyperparameter.

Apart from the type of model you are training, convergence also depends on the distribution of data, and the optimizer you are using.
The rough estimate you can make by looking at the number of parameters you have in your model, check time for one epoch, and get a rough idea from "experience" on the number of epochs. BUT you always have to look at the training and validation loss curves to check for the convergence.

Comment: IDK why, but by your name, you appear to be a teenager. I'm impressed you're into machine learning at such an early age... There are only few who actually nail it!